# Query with date range for unsold products in oscommerce

Tags: mysql, sql, oscommerce

I have the Query below to check for unsold Products in my oscommerce store.

> $products_query_raw = "
>       select p.products_id, p.products_quantity, p.products_model, pd.products_name from (" . TABLE_PRODUCTS . " p,  " .
>   TABLE_PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION . " pd) LEFT JOIN " . TABLE_ORDERS_PRODUCTS
>   . " op ON p.products_id = op.products_id where op.products_id IS NULL
>   and p.products_id = pd.products_id order by p.products_model";

This seems to work fine, but I want to limit it to search for unsold products within a date range.
The dates for the orders are located in the table ORDERS and the ordered products in the table ORDER_PRODUCTS.

I tried a few things but I cant seem to get it right, if there is anyone that can help me out I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I literally just asked almost this same question this morning but in more general terms  [MySQL Querying Multiple Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25727127/mysql-querying-multiple-tables).

@evanv did a great job explaining the trick of it... Also, @aphextwix pointed out a great tutorial for using JOINs http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/

The part that was screwing me up was the LEFT JOIN and the sub-query.

Here is the query I think you want in oscommerce terms...

```
$number_of_days = "7";
$unsold_products_query = tep_db_query("SELECT a.* FROM " . TABLE_PRODUCTS . " AS a LEFT JOIN (SELECT products_id FROM " . TABLE_ORDERS_PRODUCTS . " as b INNER JOIN " . TABLE_ORDERS . " AS c ON b.orders_id = c.orders_id WHERE c.date_purchased >= date_sub(c.date_purchased, INTERVAL " . $number_of_days . " day) GROUP BY products_id) AS d ON a.products_id = d.products_id WHERE d.products_id IS NULL");
$unsold_products_array = tep_db_fetch_array($unsold_products_query);
```

You will of course need to replace c.date_purchased in the date_sub() function if you want to use a date other than the date of the last purchase of that item.

Hope it helps.